# Online and local sql database synchronization

Tags: sql, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

According to my system i have maintained two databases in LAN and online db.But i want to synchronize these two databases. I hope to do this things using microsoft sync frame work.
 **.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819079.aspx**

Can i do sync local and online sql db using this? or any suitable method for do this.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync Framework is designed for occasionally connected systems, eg. a laptop that can access the corporate network every other day and update its database, but needs to work when it has no corpnet access too. The pairing of Sync Framework is usually a central DB (SQL Server) and local embedded SQL Server Compact or SQL Express on the devices (laptops, phones, tablets etc).

IF the databases are always connected (eg. two DBs in two servers, with 24x7 connectivity between them, even if over Internet) then the appropriate technology is replication. Either [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [Transactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706%28v=sql.105%29). Theoretically replication also works when disconnect periods are expected, but Sync Framework is much better at it, and most importantly Sync Framework is not strongly dependent on DNS names as replication is (very important for occasionally connected systems).

Synchronizing the database is a vague term, you have to consider if you want a Master-Slave replication shcme or a Master-Master (the later being *very* difficult to achieve) and you have to consider *what* do you want replicated from the database. You also need to consider if more partners will be later added (more databases to 'synchronize'). And you have to be *way* more careful now about [schema changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870).

Comment: Thank you.I thnk sql replication is the best solution of my work...Is it possible to do with online and offline replications?

Comment: That would depend a lot on what you understand by 'online and offline replications'. While I can try a guess at what you mean I prefer not to. These are not standard terminology with regard to these technologies so you better explain.

Comment: ok.One of my database in virtual dedicated server and other database in local machine.I'm trying to synchronize these two servers.

Comment: If the virtual hosting environment allows for SQL replication then it should be no problem, as long as your 'local' is a fixed name (DNS name does not change). If your 'local' is mobile (ie. changes DNS name as it connects) or it sits behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), then Sync Framework is a better choice.  A VPN can overcome both issues of name stability and NAT.